# запрос с помощью Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit

Приветствую всех!
Заранее прошу прощения, ибо я новичок в этом деле...
Ситуацию следующая : я хочу отправить на сайт POST запрос , с указанным мною логин и паролем, а в ответ получить хоть какую либо информацию. В итоге после отправки запроса в логе получаю ответ null. Ткните что я делаю не так, код привожу ниже :

Мой интерфейс :

public interface Link {

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("site/login")
Call<User> authentication(@Field(value = "ClientUsers[email]") String email,
                          @Field(value = "ClientUsers[password]") String password);
```

}

Класс пользователя :

public class User {

```
public String login;
public String password;
```

}

Главная активность :

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText etEMAIL;
EditText etPASS;
Button bLOGIN;


private static final String URL = "http://labo-pbei.no-ip.org:10001/";
private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();
Link link = retrofit.create(Link.class);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etEMAIL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEMAIL);
    etPASS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPASS);


    bLOGIN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLOGIN);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    bLOGIN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Call<User> call = link.authentication(etEMAIL.getText().toString(),etPASS.getText().toString());
            call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                    Log.d("LOGO", String.valueOf(response.body()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: А чего сразу в `body`-то? Надо статусы HTTP сначала смотреть, ошибки связи, потом уже в тело ответа.

Comment: попробовал response.message() и в ответ получил Bad Request, насколько я  понимаю это не правильный запрос? а правильный как определить ?

Comment: Да, это значит HTTP 400, смотрите запрос или спрашивайте у разработчиков бэкенда, что не так.